# Using Conditional Statement in ASP.NET Control Attribute

Tags: asp.net, binding, model

I have a DropDownList on my page and I would like the DataTextField value to be based on a condition (language).  I'm using Model Binding and this DropDown is nested in a bound FormView.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ItemType="BLL.HelperClasses.ItemForList" 
                                     DataValueField="id" DataTextField="<%#: (this.IsEnglish) ? "en" : "fr" %>" SelectMethod="DropDownList1_GetData" 
                                     SelectedValue="<%#: Item.Claim.CurrencyID %>" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

.NET is complaining that my DataTextField "server tag is not well formed".  IsEnglish is a boolean property in my base page.

Anyone know how to do this without using the code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the surrounding double-quotes.  Changed them to single-quotes and everything works perfectly.

Final solution:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" ItemType="BLL.HelperClasses.ItemForList" 
                  DataValueField="id" DataTextField='<%#: (this.IsEnglish) ? "en" : "fr" %>' SelectMethod="DropDownList1_GetData" 
                  SelectedValue="<%#: Item.Claim.CurrencyID %>" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have "Eval" inserted so for it to actually compare them don't you?

```
<asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" text="<%# Eval("StReply") == true ? "yes" : "no" %>"     xmlns:asp="#unknown">
</asp:label>
```

Code was used from http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/653888/using-If-statement-in-Bind-Eval

Comment: Doesn't work. 1) Eval needs to be cast to bool at minimum.  2) Still gives me the YSOD complaining about the tag being ill-formed.  Checked the other solution in the link you provided, still no dice.